# How to "alert" a certain element of a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var bioscoopprompt = prompt('Kies een bioscoop uit: 1, 2, 3');
var zaalprompt = prompt('Kies een zaal uit: 1, 2, 3');
var bioscoop = [ 
['','Zaal 1','Zaal 2','Zaal 3'],
['bioscoop 1','The Road','Zwart Water','Into The Wild'],
['bioscoop 2','Oorlogswinter','Avatar','Mar Adentro'],
['bioscoop 3','Dogtooth','The Road','Avatar']]
if(bioscoopprompt == '3' &&
        zaalprompt == '3' )
    {
        alert('Avatar in bio 3 zaal 3 is uitverkocht!');
    } else {
        alert('Now Showing: ' + 
document.write('<br>' + bioscoop);
```

In line 13 I need to make an `alert` that shows the chosen movie.
I have a multidemensional array, and I can let the user input the `zaal` and `bioscoop` they want to go to.

Now if they insert 3 and 3, it shows

> Avatar in bio3 zaal 3 is uitverkocht

But if they chose 1 and 2, it should show the movie that's playing in those theaters.
I hope I made the explanation as clear as possible and really hope someone can help me!

Thanks!

Comment: give an example what should show your alert

Comment: I am not sure I understood, but did you try: alert(‘Now Showing: ‘ + bioscoop[bioscoopprompt][zaaprompt]) ?

Comment: Thanks Ahmed! That worked, i know the explanation was bad. But thanks so much!

Comment: You’re most welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert('Now Showing: ' + bioscoop[bioscoopprompt][zaalprompt]);
```

should work